# i need to check for every commit made in the branch, need list the changed, added & deleted files in Git

Tags: git, github

I need to list all the changed, deleted & added  files from a branch in one line. later put added and modified in one file called added_or_modified.txt and dleted into deleted.txt. is there any way to find changed, added & deleted files in one line?

Comment: Do you mean changed in the last commit compared to the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

*(Since you're not mentionning between which states you want to diff, I've assumed the simplest context, diffing against HEAD. If you try to see diff between other given states, feel free to add it to your question, I'll adapt my answer)*

I'd do something along the lines of

```
git diff --name-status
```

You'll have letters symbolizing file status before file names :

```
A added
C changed
D deleted
M modified
R renamed
T changed
U unmerged
X unknown
B broken pairing
```

See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) for details about these states.

---

And for a deleted files list in a file (same principle for other states), you can do

```
git diff --diff-filter=D > deleted.txt
```

Comment: I think the original question wants to compare every commit in history (for each commit, compare with its parent commit).

Comment: @GenoChen Mmmh, you might be right. Rajesh, want to clarify? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says you need to check each commit.  In that case perhaps you mean something like `git log`.  On the other hand, your description of the output sounds like you just want one list of files (or, later, two).  That suggests `git diff` instead.

```
git log --name-only --format="" <upstream_branch_name>..<branch_name>
```

or

```
git diff --name-only <upstream_branch_name>..<branch_name>
```

For example, if you're checking a branch named `my_feature` and want to know what's changed in each commit since since it diverged from a `develop` branch, you could say

```
git log --name-only --format="" develop..my_feature
```

Here I've used `--format=""` so that you *just* get a list of filenames; if you're generating a list per commit, you might want to do something different with the `format` option.  I mention it because, as written, a file could appear multiple times - even showing up once because commit `A` created it, and again because commit `B` deleted it.  If that's not desirable, and you just want the net change associated with the branch, use `diff` instead of `log`.

Down the line you could change that to

```
git log --name-status --format="" develop..my_feature
```

or

```
git diff --name-status develop..my_feature
```

and process the results to separate the deletes to their own file.  Be aware that with `--name-status`, git will by default apply rename detection.  So you might get some lines like

```
D    file1
A    file2
M    file3
```

which is what you would want to see.  The one starting with `D` was deleted, so put it in the delete list; the others were added and modified.  But you also might get some lines like

```
R99  fileX   fileY
```

meaning that git thinks you've renamed `fileX` to `fileY` and made minor modifications in the same commit.  If you'd rather git just give you

```
D    fileX
A    fileY
```

so that you see simply which paths appear and disappear individually, then add the `--no-renames` option, as

```
git diff --name-status --no-renames develop..my_feature
```